# Getting Query Error - Multi-part identifier - Could not be bound for my SQL code

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error

> The multi-part identifier for ColumnName could not be bound in response to my SQL code.

Here are the particulars:

Objective of my code: Trying to identify records in a column (`FirstFourLastName`) from another table which carries a similarly named column and generate a new table.

My code for your reference:

```
Select * from [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$'] CC
  Select FirstFourLastName from [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].[PowerQuery$] PQ
  Select * from [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$'] CC
  Select FirstFourLastName from [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].[PowerQuery$] PQ
________________________________________________________________________



SELECT 
  FirstFourLastName.[CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$']
  FROM [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].[PowerQuery$]
  LEFT JOIN [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$'] 
  ON PQ.FirstFourLastName = CC.FirstFourLastName
```

As part of my research effort before posting this question here, I believe I have successfully assigned an alias to each table. For example my table: `[CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$']` has an alias CC and my table `[CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].[PowerQuery$]` has been assigned an alias PQ.

When I executed only the assigning of alias to both my tables, my code was executed successfully. However, I am getting errors when I try to execute the Join command.

Any help that can help me overcome this problem will be appreciated. I am not a developer by profession but keen to learn and solve this problem that I have been facing as part of one of the projects at my workplace.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server please correct your tags.

Comment: You can't use an alias from a different query, you need to alias the table in each query you write. `FirstFourLastName.[CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$']` is wrong because `FirstFourLastName` is a column, not a server, you should put it at the end, and if you aliased properly you would write `SELECT CC.FirstFourLastName FROM [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].[PowerQuery$] PQ LEFT JOIN [CNIS_Commissions].[dbo].['CNIS_Risk_Client Codes$'] CC ON PQ.FirstFourLastName = CC.FirstFourLastName`. The actual error you are getting is strange, as `ColumnName` does not appear anywhere in your code

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I just used ColumnName as a placeholder, I meant the error I had been getting was: The multi-part identifier for FirstFourLastName could not be bound.